# $cordovaLocalNotification not cancelable, like a shortcut in the statusbar

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, notifications, foreground

How can I create a foreground notification with `Ionic`?

I want to create a notification that can not be canceled (`ongoing: true`) and which cannot be removed when I click on it...

As I know, the attribute "*autocancel*" is deprecated (doesn't work), so... I think the `every` attribute is what I need... but I don't know in what way...

My code:

```
$cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
        id: 1234,
        title: 'Test',
        text: 'This is a test',
        ongoing: true,
        every: 1, // The notification repeats every seconds... x_x
        icon: "icon"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The new `every` function accepts the following parameters: `second`, `minute`, `hour`, `day`, `week`, `month` and `year`. This information can be found [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/Upgrade-Guide#whats-different) and also [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/Upgrade-Guide#whats-different).

So all you would have to do in your case is change `every` to `'second'`, as shown here:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Test',
        text: 'This is a test',
        ongoing: true,
        every: 'second',
        icon: "icon"
    });
});
```

---

**EDIT:** The every attribute should have been `'second'` and not `'seconds'`, also there was a parenthesis missing. More importantly, this function should be wrapped inside a function that checks whether the platform is ready, otherwise the plugin for notifications will not work.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer.  I tried this before, but the notification is removed and reopen every time the user clicks on it... I want a "fixed notification", like a shortcut in the status bar. Do you know what can I do? :( I can't find the solution...

Comment: I don't think that it is possible on iOS, but on Android the attribute you are looking for is called `ongoing`, as you know, if you set that to `true` it will stay in the notification tray, but only on Android. You can find some additional information on it [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/04.-Scheduling#interface) and also [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing%28boolean%29). Are you targeting Android only or also iOS?

Comment: Hi Dexter! My app is for both... But if the notification only works for android doesnt matter. But I can't make it work... I hace a geolocation service who send coordinates every 15 seconds and I want to show an icon in the statusbar... And I dont know if the garbage collector will remove my app if i havent got a foreground notification.. (In android i need this)

Comment: @MartaGom I tested it on an Android device and it worked for me, the notification could not be dismissed and stayed in the tray. The code I posted has been updated, since it had some mistakes, I have also added some remarks.